# JsonResult in Swagger documentation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I'm using `Swashbuckle` to generate documentation for my ASP MVC Web API. Everything works great, except documentation to JsonResult. Here is an example. I have a test class:

```
public class Test
{
    public string Testing { get; set; }
}
```

and method in controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult<Test> GetTest()
{
    Test test = new Test { Testing = "testing json" };

    return Json(test);
}
```

Based on this configuration, Swagger generates example value:

```
{
    "Content": {
        "Testing": "string"
    },
    "SerializerSettings": {
        "ReferenceLoopHandling": 0,
        "MissingMemberHandling": 0,
        "ObjectCreationHandling": 0,
        "NullValueHandling": 0,
        "DefaultValueHandling": 0,
        "Converters": [{
                "CanRead": true,
                "CanWrite": true
            }
        ],
        "PreserveReferencesHandling": 0,
        "TypeNameHandling": 0,
        "MetadataPropertyHandling": 0,
        "TypeNameAssemblyFormat": 0,
        "TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling": 0,
        "ConstructorHandling": 0,
        "ContractResolver": {},
        "EqualityComparer": {},
        "ReferenceResolver": {},
        "ReferenceResolverProvider": {
            "Method": {},
            "Target": {}
        },
        "TraceWriter": {
            "LevelFilter": 0
        },
        "Binder": {},
        "SerializationBinder": {},
        "Error": {},
        "Context": {
            "m_additionalContext": {},
            "m_state": 1
        },
        "DateFormatString": "string",
        "MaxDepth": 0,
        "Formatting": 0,
        "DateFormatHandling": 0,
        "DateTimeZoneHandling": 0,
        "DateParseHandling": 0,
        "FloatFormatHandling": 0,
        "FloatParseHandling": 0,
        "StringEscapeHandling": 0,
        "Culture": "string",
        "CheckAdditionalContent": true
    },
    "Encoding": {
        "m_codePage": 0,
        "dataItem": {
            "m_dataIndex": 0,
            "m_uiFamilyCodePage": 0,
            "m_webName": "string",
            "m_headerName": "string",
            "m_bodyName": "string",
            "m_flags": 0
        },
        "m_isReadOnly": true,
        "encoderFallback": {
            "bIsMicrosoftBestFitFallback": true
        },
        "decoderFallback": {
            "bIsMicrosoftBestFitFallback": true
        }
    },
    "Request": {}
}
```

Which is incorrect. I don't want a documentation for `JsonResult`, but only for my `Test` class. How can I change that? How can I tell Swagger to prepare documentation only for `Test` class?

Comment: try with just: `public Test GetTest()`

Comment: another option will be to use `SwaggerResponse` take a look at the sample: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/blob/5489aca0d2dd7946f5569341f621f581720d4634/Swashbuckle.Dummy.Core/Controllers/SwaggerAnnotatedController.cs#L15

Comment: Can you confirm what version of the asp.net platform you are using. Asp.net MVC 5 + Web API 2 or asp.net Core?

Comment: I cannot use just `public Test GetTest()` because I use `Json` method with different serialization and encoding settings. Yes, I'm using asp mvc 5 + web api 2, not a .net core. `SwaggerResponse` solved the problem. Thank you. You can post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is be to use SwaggerResponse take a look at this sample:

```
[SwaggerResponse(400, "Bad request")]
public class SwaggerAnnotatedController : ApiController
{
    [SwaggerResponseRemoveDefaults]
    [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, Type = typeof(int))]
    [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Invalid message", typeof(HttpError))] 
    public int Create(Message message)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

---

Here is a link to the project:

https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/blob/5489aca0d2dd7946f5569341f621f581720d4634/Swashbuckle.Dummy.Core/Controllers/SwaggerAnnotatedController.cs#L15